# For my if-else statement, the else should display, not the if. I dont know why

Tags: python

when I enter 3, it should display, "you are a curious person", but instead it displays "you are an optimistic person". Why is this

```
eyeList = ["blue", "brown","green","hazel","grey","none"]

print(eyeList)

eyecolor = int(input("Pick your eye color: "))

if eyecolor == 1 or 2:

  print("you are a  optimistic person")

else:

  print("you are a curious person")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using
`if eyecolor == 1 or eyecolor == 2` or `eyecolor == (1 or 2)`. Since you are using an if statement without parentheses, Python is interpreting the two if statements separately. `eyecolor == 1` is false but `2` which is an int always evaluates to True.